# Web scraping using R to download a large dataset

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to download a large dataset made available online for public use by the Government of India. The [url](https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=23&Tx_State=0&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-Jan-2005&DateTo=31-Dec-2005&Fr_Date=01-Jan-2005&To_Date=31-Dec-2005&Tx_Trend=2&Tx_CommodityHead=Onion&Tx_StateHead=--Select--&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--) used below accesses the daily quantities and prices of onion at different wholesale markets across India. I need the following variables on a daily frequency from January 2005 to December 2005 in a table format: State name, District name, Market name, Variety name, Commodity name, Arrival quantity, Minimum price, Maximum price, and Modal price- all of which are available from the online database. It is too large for manual copy-paste.

I am trying to automate the web scraping process using R. The following is the code I tried. But it leads to the error "Error in data[[1](https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=23&Tx_State=0&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-Jan-2005&DateTo=31-Dec-2005&Fr_Date=01-Jan-2005&To_Date=31-Dec-2005&Tx_Trend=2&Tx_CommodityHead=Onion&Tx_StateHead=--Select--&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--)] : subscript out of bounds". I am new to web scraping and not sure how to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

# Specify the URL
url <- "https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=23&Tx_State=0&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-Jan-2005&DateTo=31-Dec-2005&Fr_Date=01-Jan-2005&To_Date=31-Dec-2005&Tx_Trend=2&Tx_CommodityHead=Onion&Tx_StateHead=--Select--&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--"

# Read the HTML content from the URL
page <- read_html_live(url)

# Extract the data using CSS selectors or XPath
# Use the 'selectorGadget' tool or browser's Inspect Element to find appropriate CSS selectors or XPath
data <- page %>%
  html_nodes("table#cphBody_GridArrivalData") %>%
  html_table()

# Extracted data will be in a list, you can access it like this:
df <- data[[1]]

# Display the data
print(df)
```

Comment: `rvest::html_elements(xpath = "//*[@id='cphBody_GridViewBoth']") |> rvest::html_table() |> purrr::pluck(1)` works for the first page. Unfortunately, the server responses (on my side of internet) is so slow, that almost impossible to execute anything. But as the following pages of the table are "hidden" by java script, I would suggest to use newest version of {rvest} with `read_html_live(url)` function. It should handle this quite well.

Comment: Thanks, will try it. The website is slow to move because I have selected a longer range of years (DateFrom=01-Jan-2005&DateTo=31-Dec-2023). It would be faster for a smaller range, say one year. Even for one year of data there are about 80-90 hidden pages. If possible, could you please suggest the code for one year range (DateFrom=01-Jan-2005&DateTo=31-Dec-2005)?

Comment: I tried using ```page <- read_html_live(url)``` but it leads to "Error: Chromote: timed out waiting for event Page.loadEventFired". I changed the code in the original question to reduce the time span to one year (January 2005 to December 2005). Could you please suggest a solution on this error.

Answer (score 2):

`"Error: Chromote: timed out waiting for event Page.loadEventFired"` is caused because `default_timeout` for chromote session is 10 sec.

```
> a <- chromote::ChromoteSession$new()
> a$default_timeout
[1] 10
```

So, we have to increase timeout for chromote session and then navigate through the pages. I wasn't able to figure out how to create `rvest::LiveHTML` session without url and increase timeout. My silly attempt is based on {chromote} itself and mouse clicks taken from {hayalbaz} [puppet()](https://github.com/rundel/hayalbaz/blob/master/R/puppet.R) function.

```r
url <- "https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=23&Tx_State=0&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-Jan-2005&DateTo=31-Jan-2005&Fr_Date=01-Jan-2005&To_Date=10-Jan-2005&Tx_Trend=2&Tx_CommodityHead=Onion&Tx_StateHead=--Select--&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--#skip"


ses <- chromote::ChromoteSession$new()
ses$default_timeout <- 10*60

ses$Page$navigate(url)
#> $frameId
#> [1] "89185E61E2C271FDB8E86100F3E3FDF7"
#> 
#> $loaderId
#> [1] "17B454E2B6863883BE803EAD65AC0FE9"
ses$Page$loadEventFired()
#> $timestamp
#> [1] 32197.85

ses$view()

t <- ses$Runtime$evaluate("document.querySelector('html').outerHTML")$result$value |>
  rvest::read_html() |>
  rvest::html_table() |>
  purrr::pluck(4)
```

Until now we have read the first page from table to `t` data frame. Number `4` in `for(){}` loop below is taken arbitrary just for testing purposes. You need to increase it especially if you extend the time period in url. You can rewrite the loop in nice function and `lapply` it .

```r
for (i in c(2:4)) {
  
  sel <- paste0("#cphBody_GridViewBoth > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(558) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(", i, ") > a:nth-child(1)")

  ses$Runtime$evaluate(
    paste0("document.querySelector('", sel , "').scrollIntoView()")
    )

  doc = ses$DOM$getDocument()
  id <- ses$DOM$querySelector(doc$root$nodeId, sel)$nodeId
  
  b <- ses$DOM$getBoxModel(id)$model$border
  x = (b[[1]] + b[[5]])/2
  y = (b[[2]] + b[[6]])/2
  
  ses$Input$dispatchMouseEvent(type="mousePressed", x=x, y=y, button="left", clickCount=1)
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  ses$Input$dispatchMouseEvent(type="mouseReleased", x=x, y=y, button="left", clickCount=1)
  Sys.sleep(30) # you may need to modify it, or even delete

  tt <- ses$Runtime$evaluate("document.querySelector('html').outerHTML")$result$value |>
    rvest::read_html() |>
    rvest::html_table() |>
    purrr::pluck(4)

  t <- tt |>
    rbind(t)
  
}

t[1:6, 1:11]
#> # A tibble: 6 × 11
#>   ``           ``    ``       ``    ``       ``    ``    ``    ``    ``    ``   
#>   <chr>        <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 NCT of Delhi Delhi Shahdara Other Vegetab… 82.80 400   600   500   08 J… <NA> 
#> 2 NCT of Delhi Delhi Shahdara Other Vegetab… 28.10 450   600   500   07 J… <NA> 
#> 3 NCT of Delhi Delhi Shahdara Other Vegetab… 23.50 450   600   500   06 J… <NA> 
#> 4 NCT of Delhi Delhi Shahdara Other Vegetab… 27.50 350   650   500   04 J… <NA> 
#> 5 NCT of Delhi Delhi Shahdara Other Vegetab… 116.… 350   650   500   03 J… <NA> 
#> 6 NCT of Delhi Delhi Shahdara Other Vegetab… 59.40 500   700   600   02 J… <NA>
nrow(t)
#> [1] 2232
nrow(unique(t))
#> [1] 2223
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-20 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the efforts. The code runs correctly up to  ```  purrr::pluck(4)```. 
When I run the loop above, I get the error "Error in onRejected(reason) : code: -32000
  message: Could not find node with given id". Sorry to bother you again, but I am new to web scraping. Could you help me fix this?

Comment: Forget about loop for a while. Just remove `for (i in c(2:4)) {` and closing `}`, put `i = 2` and run the code line by line. Does the error appears? I do suspect the error is caused by timing.

Comment: Yes, the error starts at the line
````b <- ses$DOM$getBoxModel(id)$model$border```` with this message:

"Error in onRejected(reason) : code: -32000
  message: Could not find node with given id"

Comment: Then maybe you have to adjust `sel(ector)`. I noticed, that changing the date from 10-Jan (as above) to 31-Dec changes the selector to `#cphBody_GridViewBoth > tbody > tr:nth-child(553) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > a` => `553` instead of `558`. Please use Inspector after `ses$view()` and click on the page number below the table and copy the appropriate selector from something like `<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphBody$GridViewBoth','Page$2')">2</a>`

Comment: Yes, there is no error when 558 is changed to 553. The code results in the second page of the data.

Comment: Good. Please adjust the url to required dates and take the proper selector. The loop (with increased range for `i` ) should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(rvest)

"https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=23&Tx_State=0&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=01-Jan-2005&DateTo=31-Dec-2005&Fr_Date=01-Jan-2005&To_Date=31-Dec-2005&Tx_Trend=2&Tx_CommodityHead=Onion&Tx_StateHead=--Select--&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--" %>% 
  session() %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  pluck(1)
```

Comment: Thanks. But this extracts only the first page of the required data. The data is spread across several pages, and I need to extract from all pages.